# Bootstrap select picker with ng-repeat is not working for JSON object

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was using Bootstrap select for search and multiple select but the problem is when i am using $scope object in ng-repeat for options it's not working . I have given my codes below .

```
<select name="name" ng-model="city.id" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" ng-options="o._id as o.name for o in stateList" ></select>

<select name="name" ng-model="city.id" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" ><option ng-repeat="option in stateList" value="{[{option._id}]}">{[{option.name}]}</option>
```

I have used both options and ng-option methods but still the object didn't show up ...

This is my state object that need to be repeated in select...

$scope.stateList = [{"_id":"1","name":"www"},{"_id":"2","name":"bgg"}]

Hope you understand my problem and if you need any more details
pls leave a comment and i'm waiting for your suggestions...

Comment: Can you please write your full code structure here...

Comment: does the code available for you now @AnilKumarRam

Comment: when i use an array like $scope.value = ['1','2','3']; i can get the value in ng-repeat and it's displayed in the dropdown but when i do it with the object none gets displayed.

Comment: i ve create fiddle for you check and reply http://jsfiddle.net/fA968/257/

Comment: As you know i'm using bootstrap-select with angularjs for search and select in dropdown and so the fiddle that you have shared consist of a normal dropdown in angularjs ... please view this link for the sample dropdown https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search and also im working on multiple select with search...

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues as well, but using nya-bootstrap-select 
http://nya.io/nya-bootstrap-select/#!/

fixed it.  It has something to do with bootstrap select's use of jQuery which doesn't always play nice with angular...this is written in Angular for use with Angular, so its more compatible...

Comment: i have used UI-Select instead of the above code which is working fine ... as you said the problem may be with the JQuery @MattE